# iOS plist is null

Tags: ios, plist

I know there are a multitude of questions about this on SO but I can't see where I am making the mistake and am hoping some extra eyes will help. I've verified the plist is in my bundle and it is also in my docs directory and it contains data. Here's a screen capture of the app package with the plist at top:

[image]

I pass the plist in from another class and have verified that it is the correct plist.

Here's my code:

```
-(id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        //set up the appTracker
        appTracker = [[OAI_AppTracker alloc] init];

        //set up a file manager and error container
        fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

        //docs directory path
        documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        //track event
        appTracker.appEvent = @"File Manager initialized";
        [appTracker recordEvent];

    }

    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary* ) readPlist {

    NSError* error;

    //set up dictionary to hold our app data
    NSDictionary* appData;

    //set up destination path
    NSString* destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", plistToRead]];

    if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){
        //read plist
        appData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:destinationPath];
    } else {

        //file doesn't exist so we have to move it to the doc folder
        NSString *sourcePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistToWrite];
        [fileManger copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

        //now read the plist
        appData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:destinationPath];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@", appData);
    return appData;

}
```

My log shows NULL instead of the data in the plist. Appreciate any help as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @mkral - no, here's the console log: 2012-11-14 14:26:00.839 OAI_IntegrationSiteReport_v1[2981:c07] AppData.plist
2012-11-14 14:26:00.840 OAI_IntegrationSiteReport_v1[2981:c07] (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read your plist try something like this:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistFileName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Comment: That worked. But I also need to write to this file. Doesn't it have to be in the docs directory to be able to write to it?

Comment: Right, but I do a check for the source in docs diret - if ([fileManger fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]){ and read if it exists or move then read if not: //file doesn't exist so we have to move it to the doc folder
        NSString *sourcePath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistToWrite];
        [fileManger copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

        //now read the plist
        appData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:destinationPath];

Comment: I've also logged within that conditional and it is logging ok for the plist existing within the docs directory (and I've confirmed that through AppSupport->iPhoneSimulator...

Comment: Try to log the error after the copyItemAtPath call, maybe there's something there?

Comment: I wonder if this is the problem - I keep deleting the plist from AppSupport->iPhoneSimulator but the app keeps acting as if it exists (i.e. I logged in the second half of the if it exists conditional but that is not being written to the console.) and when I check the directory it is there.

Comment: Eh, I deleted the plist and added a new one and it worked. Go figure.